# Como acionar o insert só quando clicar no botão de inserir

Tags: php

Eu tenho um form que todas as vezes que é dado post, ele está dando erro por falta de parâmetro. Eu gostaria de dar insert somente quando alguém clicar no botão de inserir (mãozinha no desenho). Pensei em desabilitar o botão para que habilitasse somente quando estiver preenchido mas não sei como proceder.
  [image: Desabilitando Insert]

https://gist.github.com/FabricioYwin/2b0483e25b030a0be54037751af78e89

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa fazer a validação dos campos.

Dá pra fazer isso em JavaScript, PHP ou nos dois.

Por exemplo em PHP:

```
if(trim($_POST['quantidade']) == ''){
    $error[] = 'Quantidade - Campo Obrigatório!';
}

if(trim($_POST['custo']) == ''){
    $error[] = 'Custo - Campo Obrigatório!';
}

if(trim($_POST['modelo']) == ''){
    $error[] = 'Modelo - Campo Obrigatório!';
}

if(count($error) > 0){
   # Volta para a página sem dar Insert
}
else{
   # Faz insert
}
```

E assim com os outros campos.

O `trim()` tira os espaços do início e final da string. Depois verifica se está vazio.

Comment: mas como eu faço para exbibir esse alerta? Posso usar o alert do bootstrap?

Comment: Sim, você pode usar. Eu faço assim: if (isset($_POST['variavel_x'])){ //se a variável existe, ou seja se existe algum conteúdo, se ela foi preenchida, ou no caso do botão, se foi clicado; }

Comment: Pode sim. Na página você verifica se existe a variável `$error`. Se sim, você mostra.